# Reference copied data to original cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference copied data, to the initial cell.
My sequence is as follows

1. Add newsheet on button click // sheetname Load1, Load2, etc
2. Input data into new sheet
3. Click Add new Load.
4. Copy specific cells
5. Paste in summary sheet

**6. Link pasted values to the original worksheet cells???**

My Code

```
Sub New_Load()


Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8 As Variant ' motor loads
Dim y1, y2, y3, y4, y5 As Variant 'UPS loads ' y5 (cell C14 with white text) sheetname

Set ws = Sheets("Tech_Form") '

Set sh = Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' This will be the last sheet in the Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

If Range("D15") = "UPS" Then

Fill_Blanks 'fill blanks with N/A

y1 = Range("D15").Value
y2 = Range("E42").Value
y3 = Range("H42").Value
y4 = Range("E46").Value
y5 = Range("C15").Value


Sheets("Summary").Select

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = y1
Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = y2
Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = y3
Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = y4
Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "kWe"
Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = y5


End If

Sheets("Load").Visible = True
Sheets("Load").Copy After:=sh


Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Load" & Sheets.Count - 4 ' number of static    sheets
'ActiveSheet.Name = Range("D15").Value

Sheets("Load").Visible = False


End Sub
```

Comment: so? what is your problem? what do you mean when you say "link", instead of values you want to display something like `=D15` in the target cell?

Comment: If `link` means via formula then you need to use `Range.Formula = "=" & Range("D15").Address` where `Range` is whatever cell you want to have that formula.  If they are on different sheets, then you need to add the sheet name to the formula as well: `"='" & Range("D15").Parent.Name & "'!" & Range("D15").Address`.

Comment: By link, I mean I want to be able to change the number at either the master or parent and both of them change. If I delete the parent sheet the   row should be deleted as well